# Why do I got an error "You must declare scalar variable @xxx"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have two tables named **SALES_TABLE** and **PRODUCT_TABLE**. So whenever I sell an item from the **product table**, the number of the sold item(sale_count) is subtracted from the total number of the same item in the stock (pr_stock) and the result gets displayed on the **Product_table** while the figures for product id(product_id) and the sale number(sale_count) is written on the **Sales_table**.

I also want the name of the sold item to be displayed in the inserted table that's why I declared variable @prd_name and initialized it with Product_name from Product Table where PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID. But I got an error in the execution like

> "You must declare scalar variable @prd_name".

What is the reason for that? How to solve it?

Note that :

```
INSERT INTO DBO.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,PROD_ID,Prod_name) VALUES (3,4, @prd_name )
```

is something should trigger the above script in the BEGIN and END scope. It doesn't have to be part of it. @prd_name should get the name of Product_Name from Product table and insert it into Prod_name column of the Sales_table.

```
alter TRIGGER DBO.TRG_STOCK
    ON DBO.SALES_TABLE
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @SALE_COUNT INT
    DECLARE @PRD_ID INT 
    declare @prd_name varchar(20) 

    SELECT @PRD_ID = PROD_ID, @SALE_COUNT = SALE_COUNT FROM INSERTED
    select @prd_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME from PRODUCT_TABLE where PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID
    UPDATE PRODUCT_TABLE SET PR_STOCK =  PR_STOCK - @SALE_COUNT WHERE PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID
    END


    INSERT INTO DBO.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,PROD_ID,Prod_name) VALUES (3,4, @prd_name )
```

Comment: You have `END` before the end of your trigger, so the `INSERT` statement can't see the `@prd_name` variable. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: You're declaring the variable within a `BEGIN...END` block, so it goes out of scope after `END`.

Comment: so why is the question 'marked down'? - since the info to be able to determine an answer is actually provided.

Comment: Any trigger that acts as if `inserted` will always contain exactly one row is inherently broken. It's made to look like a table *because* it can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. For a multi-row insert, your trigger will pick *a* `Prod_ID` value from one of those rows and ignore the others.

Comment: @Cato The downvote is for questions that are "not useful" and this one isn't useful.

Comment: @DavidG that's very kind of you :) downvoting the question that maybe is not useful for you but other in the beginner level of sql

Comment: @CavidHummatov You misunderstand the intention. First, the question you have posted is not useful to anyone but you, that makes it off topic here. Second, I gave you the answer in my first comment so I already helped you.

Comment: The answer is definitely useful however I cannot see that the question asked was poor or unhelpful.  Is that right, that a question has to be useful to other people?  How could the questioner know that?   I find that an odd definition of 'off topic', quite concerning in fact.  I like to think that I'm primarily helping people if I post here, I didn't realise that we were supposed to be some sort of research academics, only building knowledge.

Comment: @Cato I'm also quite baffled about what kind of a question should I ask for not be downvoted or marked as "useless".. This is my concern and I ask it. How could I decide if it's helpful or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger end at `END` (surprise that), but you reference `@prd_name` after the `END`. A variable only exists within the same batch it was created, thus when you run your `INSERT` statement, `@prd_name` no longer exists.

Your trigger, however, is flawed, it expects only one row to ever be inserted at a time; if you inserted 2 (or more), then the trigger won't work as you expect. This *might* be what you are after, which will handle more than 1 row in the `INSERT` statement.:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TRG_STOCK
ON dbo.SALES_TABLE
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE PT
    SET PR_STOCK = PT.PR_STOCK - i.SALE_COUNT
    FROM inserted i
         JOIN PRODUCT_TABLE PT ON i.Prod_id = PT.PRODUCT_id;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,
                             PROD_ID,
                             Prod_name)
    SELECT 3,4,PT.PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM inserted i
         JOIN PRODUCT_TABLE PT ON i.Prod_id = PT.PRODUCT_id;
END;
```

Comment: Downvote why..? This answer isn't solely addressing the OP's typo but the fact that their trigger is flawed. It will only ever handle 1 row as it is in their Question.

Comment: Not mine, but as others have already pointed out, an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that inserts into the same table doesn't make a great deal of sense, so it's quite unclear what the OP is currently trying to achieve.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, the `UPDATE` on `PRODUCT_TABLE ` is still an issue in their question as well mind, Unfortunately, a comment isn't a good place to show examples of moving from a scalar to dataset approach. Apparently, whomever voted this down feels that isn't useful. Interesting. 

Comment: Also not my DV, but I would say that saying your code *might* be what OP is after suggests that it shouldn't be there at all. I also think it's not what they want. It looks like the trigger is there to update a stock table when a sale is made so the final INSERT is just not needed, especially when the trigger happens *after* the insert has already completed.

Comment: @Larnu I'm also aware that my trigger is ill-formed. I'm just practising on the different sides of it while consolidating my syntax knowledge about it. I thank you for not witholding your suggestion from me to make it better.. I'm learning from  all.